# Is there a password policy configuration for setting up expiration date on cisco IOS?

Tags: cisco-ios

Even I tried to find it from cisco homepage..
It seems it doesn't exist.

Is that only possible to set up on TACACS+ or RADIUS?

Comment: What version do you have?

Comment: you need 16.5 or later, and need to enable aaa

Comment: @RonTrunk thx a lot I solved it!

Comment: @RonTrunk aaa common-criteria policy ~~~~ life time 3 month